# Mac calendar not syncing with iphone

Tags: iphone, mac, data-synchronization, calendar

My icalendar on mac syncs with my ipad but my iphone calendar is not syncing with these for some reason. Does anybody know a fix for this?

Comment: Are you using the same Apple ID on the mac and the phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For syncing to occur on macOS, you have to be signed in to iCloud with the same [AppleID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_ID) as on the other devices.

Check *System Preferences* → *Internet Accounts*

After signing in, ensure Calendars is ticked.

[image: Image of System Preferences Internet Accounts when signed in to iCloud]

You also have to be connected to a network.